# how to find the login and password fields of a website

Tags: ios, web-services, asihttprequest

I'm trying to log onto a website for my iPhone app. How do I find out the name of the fields for the username and password?  I tried viewing the source using the javascript console but that doesn't seem to be working for me.  If it is, then I don't understand why I'm getting a connection error.

Comment: It's rather unclear what you want to do. If you want to send some information to a website, why don't you just create an HTTP-Request?

Comment: I actually had an extra"/" in the http://...oops.  Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some websites deliberately obfuscate their login page, using JavaScript, so as to try and prevent software from using the web site.

[The Motley Fool](http://www.fool.com/) is one website that does this.  I'm sure there are others.

Comment: Is there a "legit" way around this...or do I have to contact the web developer?